# Python: How to parse variables from several pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I want to extract the `x` and `y` variables from several pandas dataframes (before proceeding to next steps). I initialize the tab-delimited `.txt` file, before I extract the information.
Error raised is `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

```
import pandas as pd

class DataProcessing:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\t")
        X, y = self.df.iloc[1:, 1:]
        return X, y

dp_linear_cna = DataProcessing("data_linear_cna.txt")
dp_mrna_seq_v2_rsem = DataProcessing("data_mrna_seq_v2_rsem.txt")

dp_linear_cna.extract_info()
dp_mrna_seq_v2_rsem.extract_info()
```

Traceback:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 0):

1. The `sep="/t"` is supposed to be `sep="\t"`.
2. Never iterate over rows/columns, select data using [index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).
   e.g. selecting a column: `df['some_column_name']`

Answer (score 0):

You coding style is quite bad. First of all, don't return anything in **init**. It's a constructor. Make another function instead.

```
class DataProcessing:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\t")

    def split_data(self):
        X = self.df.iloc[:, :-1]
        y = self.df.iloc[:, -1]
        return X, y
```

Calling your DataProcessing like this:

```
def main():
    dp = DataProcessing('data_linear_cna.txt')
    X, y = dp.split_data()
    print(X)
    print()
    print(y)
```

Main point here is selection over position via df.iloc[rows, columns]

```
X, y = self.df.iloc[1:, 1:]
```

this is not a valid statement. **pandas.DataFrame.iloc** return another **pandas.DataFrame**. Not a tuple. You can't do tuple unpacking.

Indexing both axes

You can mix the indexer types for the index and columns. Use : to select the entire axis.